# Problem with granting permission for bluetooth in flutter and flutter-blue

Tags: flutter

I developed a simple app using the [flutter-blue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue) package. The application works fine in the debug mode. Now I want to publish a release APK to install it on other devices.

This is my Android Manifest file:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

The APK is built successfully but the installed application does not work. It seems that there exist some problems with the permissions.

I've tried following workarounds from various git issues:

1. Using --no-shrink parameter when building. Results in larger apk file but nothing changes.
2. Using [permission-handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) package and adding this in the main function:

Code:

```
checkPerm() async {    
var status = await Permission.bluetooth.status;
if (status.isDenied) {
 
  await Permission.bluetooth.request();
}

if (await Permission.bluetooth.status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
  openAppSettings();
}

}
```

And:

```
void main() {

  checkPerm();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
      .then((_) {
    runApp(BleApp());
  });
}
```

None of the above solutions worked for me. The flutter-blue error is: **Error starting scan**

The apk-debug build is working correctly and granting the permissions as well.

General info:

```
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 28
Flutter version 2.0.4
Dart version 2.12.2
flutter_blue: ^0.8.0
provider: ^5.0.0
permission_handler: ^7.0.0
```

Tested on Android version 5.1 and 10.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/issues/662

Answer (score 5):

Add to build.gradle like this

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
```

And delete the old app from device, then `flutter clean` and `flutter run --release`.
It worked for me